# Applying LUT on 12 or 16 bit byte array or Mat

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Is there an efficient way of applying LUT (look up table of the camera which is derived from a curve that can be configured by user) on 12 or 16 bit image?

Currently I'm using EmguCV for applying noise reduction and edge enhancement. I need to apply LUT on 12 and 16 bit images (stored as byte array).

Currently there is only support for 8bit images.

Comment: You should probably describe what "LUT" means in this context. I.e. do you have a slope+intercept? center + width? an actual lookup table?

Comment: @JonasH it's an actual lookup table of the camera from which the image is acquired.

Comment: `cv::LUT` only supports 8-bit currently. you _can_ write this yourself. it's just a per-pixel loop with `new_value := LUT[old_value]` -- since you're talking about camera pictures, be aware that "LUT" may also be understood as 4-6 bpc 3D LUT for "looks".